# Searching for non numeric characters, except for a ".", using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've been using "(\D)" to find the end of a string of numbers, but it also detects decimal points, how can the regex key be changed to allow for the detection of all non numeric characters except for a ".".

Answer (score 7):

> how can the regex key be changed to allow for the detection of all non numeric characters except for a "."

```
[^\d.]
```

This pattern matches any non-digit character but not of a dot.

Comment: More precisely, it matches anything not contained in the set of (digits or `.`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with:

```
[^0-9.]
```

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way is using character class **\D** with the character **.**

```
[\D.]
```